# Number of ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/a \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{P}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Number of ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/a \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{P}$.

I thought about using the fact, that the kernel of a ring homomorphism needs to be an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/a \mathbb{Z}$ and a subgroup of the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/a \mathbb{Z}$.
Let $f$ be such an ring homomorphism hence yields that $|f^{-1}(0)| \in {1,a,a^2}$.

Is it possible to proceed from here or what's a better way to go?

Comment: I believe $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of all positive primes in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of primes in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Can you find out the number of homomorphisms in the case $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Try it for a few fixed primes and see if you can spot a pattern. try $a=b=2$ then $a=2$, $b=3$.

Comment: I'm unsure. Am I right: for $a=b=2$ there are two ring homomorphisms, for $a=2,b=3$ there are 3 ring homomorphisms? Basically starting from the idea that $(1,1) \mapsto 1$ in any case and then checking the possibilities for $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a ring homomorphism, the map must take $1$ to $1$.

$\mathbb Z/a\mathbb Z$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}/a \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/a \mathbb{Z}$ via the diagonal embedding. The image of this subring under the homomorphism realizes $\mathbb Z/a\mathbb Z$ as a subring of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. Since $p$ is a prime, this is impossible unless $a=p$.

Answer (score 1):

It's often easier to do algebra with rings when you express them as quotients of polynomial rings or similar.

We know that $\mathbb{Z} / p \times \mathbb{Z}/p$ contains $\mathbb{Z} / p$ along its diagonal. But how to capture the rest of it?

Well, we can do this by adjoining $(0,1)$ to the diagonal copy of $\mathbb{Z} / p$. Its minimal polynomial is $x^2 - x$, and so I claim:

$$ \mathbb{Z} / p \times \mathbb{Z} / p \cong (\mathbb{Z} / p) [x] / (x^2 - x) $$

The inverse sends $x \mapsto (0,1)$. The forward direction sends $(1,0) \to 1 - x$ and $(0,1) \to x$. These are both ring homomorphisms, so we see the sketch above gives a correct result.

Thus, your goal is to find homomorphisms

$$ (\mathbb{Z} / a) [x] / (x^2 - x) \to \mathbb{Z} / b$$

which you can do with the powerful tools for describing homomorphisms from such rings.